# How do I allow filter booleans to be non-mutually exclusive?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to filter my results using an object with values that are either `true` or `false`. However, these filters are not mutually exclusive, meaning more than one can be true.

The code shown only allows one filter to work, I assume I need to figure out a way to make `showData` dynamic but I'm not too sure how.

```
const filters = {
  letter: {
    A: false,
    B: false,
    C: false,
    D: false,
    E: false
  },
  number: {
    1: false,
    2: false,
    3: false,
    4: false
  },
  //...
};

const data = [
  {
    letter: "A",
    number: "1",
  },
  {
    letter: "B",
    number: "1",
  },
  {
    letter: "B",
    number: "2",
  },
  //...
],

const results = data.map((result, index) => {
  let showData = true;

  if (filters.letter.A) showData = result.letter === "A";
  if (filters.letter.B) showData = result.letter === "B";
  //...

  return (showData && result)
})}
```

An example of expected output is if both `filters.letter.A` and `filters.letter.B` were `true`, then `results` would return an array of objects matching these two filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct an array of the truthy keys in `filters.letter` in advance, and then you can set `showCard` based on whether the `.letter` of the current card being iterated over is included in that array:

```
const trueLetterKeys = Object.entries(filters.letter)
  .filter(([, val]) => val)
  .map(([key]) => key);
// ...
{data.map(({ letter }, index) => {
  const showCard = trueLetterKeys.includes(letter);
  // ...
```

Doesn't matter when there aren't many items, but to reduce complexity you could use a `Set` of truthy keys instead of an array, since a `Set`'s `.has` is quicker than an array's `.includes`:

```
const trueLetterKeys = new Set(
  Object.entries(filters.letter)
    .filter(([, val]) => val)
    .map(([key]) => key)
);
// ...
{data.map(({ letter }, index) => {
  const showCard = trueLetterKeys.has(letter);
  // ...
```

Comment: Got it bit stumped by `.filter(([, val]) => val)` and just realised is the same as `.filter(([key, value]) => value)`, incase this clarification might help others, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need that any condition should set showDara, but not clear it.

Simple solution:

```
//...
if (letter.A) showData = showData || data.letter ===‘A’;
if (letter.B) showData = showData || data.letter ===‘B’;
//...
```

Advanced:

If I correct in guessing your data, you may simplify the code.

This code will work in case data.letter and data.number is reasonable sanitized values that not interfere with build in or inherited properties:

```
//...
if(letter[data.letter] === true) showData = true;
if(number[data.number] === true) showData = true;
//...
```

More advanced:

This code looks more correct, but bit more complex:
(Using hasOwnProperty method to check that property defined in object itself and not inherited from parent object):

```
//...
if(letter.hasOwnProperty(data.letter) && letter[data.letter] === true) showData = true;
if(number.hasOwnProperty(data.number) && number[data.number] === true) showData = true;
//...
```